# popup to display selected options using javascript or ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i have a HTML code in which user can select multiple options. As the user is selcting options, the selected options should be displayed in either a popup using ajax or a div...I have already tried using selectbox with checkbox but that doesn't work and it became difficult to fetch parameters for further usage in perl cgi script. There is no code available for this..What is the easy way to get the selected options in a popup? i want the options to be displayed in the popup as they are getting selected.

HTML code:

```
<td>Server Name <font color = red>*</font></td>
<td>
    <span title="Press the 'ctrl' key to select multiple servers">
        <select name="serverlist" id="slist" size="4" multiple>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select servers</option>
            <option>Server 1</option>
            <option>Server 2</option>
            <option>Server 3</option>
            <option>Server 4</option>
            <option>Server 5</option>
        </select>
    </span>
</td>
```

Comment: You can keep a button below the list and get the selected checkboxes. Then on click of button just do whatever you want.

Comment: can this be achieved without using a button? @rach8garg  ?

Comment: I'm writing up an answer for this, but just wanted to say - have you tried chosen() library for jquery? it's pretty popular and nice - won't do exactly what you said bu perhaps give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the selected options.
You need to add onchange event first, and loop the options and get the selected values. Something like this:

```
<td>Server Name 
    <font color = red>*</font>
</td>
<td>
    <span title="Press the 'ctrl' key to select multiple servers">
        <select name="serverlist" id="slist" onChange="getSelectedServers()" size="4" multiple>
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select servers</option>
            <option>Server 1</option>
            <option>Server 2</option>
            <option>Server 3</option>
            <option>Server 4</option>
            <option>Server 5</option>
        </select>
    </span>
</td>
<div id="displaySelectedServers">

</div>
<script>
    function getSelectedServers() {
        var e = document.getElementById("slist");
        var serversList = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < e.options.length; i++) {
            if (e.options[i].selected) {
                serversList += '| ' + e.options[i].value + ' |';
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("displaySelectedServers").innerHTML = serversList;     
    }
</script>
```

I hope my answer was helpful :)

Comment: You are welcome. As it was helpful can you please upvote my answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

Additional html for pop up div:

```
<div id=popUp>
</div>
```

addition CSS for popUp div:

```
#popUp{
  display: none;            // required if div is to "pop up" on change.
  border: 1px solid black;  // optional, put it here to give an idea on how to approach working with this div.
  border-radius:4px;        // optional
  width:200px;              // optional
  min-height: 100px;        // optional
}

#popUp>p{
  display: inline-block;    // optional
  margin: 5px;              // optional
}
```

and the jQuery to listen to changes in the select element iterate through the options to review which are selected and display the text content of those also in the pop up div:

```
$("select#slist").change(function(){                          // Listen to <select> changes
        $("div#popUp").show().empty();                        // Make sure popUp is shown and cleared of contents.
        $(this).find("option").each(function(index, value){   // Find options, iterate through them
            if($(value).prop("selected")){                    // check if option is selected
        $("div#popUp").append(`<p>${$(value).text()}</p>`)    // append option text content to popUp
        }
    });
});
```